# While installing Magento I'm getting the error PHP Extensions pdo_mysql must be loaded

Tags: php, magento

After I've done on local I installed magento 1.9 on server. As I uploaded all the files on server and tried to install magento, It gave me error-

```
 PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded.
```

someone please tell me what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: so you error is not while *installing PHP* but while *installing magento*... also. have you tried *installing the php-mysql-drivers*?

Comment: Actually I'm doing this first time on server, so like local I just upload all the files on server and tried to install, A starting page of magento had been open but on the next page where we fill the data base details, It's giving the above error. Do we need to upload more things on server while installing magento?

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy ;)

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

More information: https://forum.piwik.org/t/you-need-to-enable-the-pdo-and-pdo-mysql-extensions-in-your-php-ini-file/261

Comment: There are often 2 different `php.ini` files. Make sure you amend the one identified in a `phpinfo()` output

Comment: I've read somewhere that we have to create php.ini file and paste this code extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
so I did not understand In which file I would have to paste your code- php.ini or php.ini.sample